# Design pattern to return appropriate class depending if autoloader detects file? Factory, Service Locator, etc?

Tags: php, design-patterns

We have a CMS which has standard implementations of Models, Mappers, Forms and DbTables, under the standard Admin_Model_Whatever, Admin_Model_Mapper_Whatever (Zend Framework 1 directory structure).

However, certain projects which share this CMS directory will sometimes need to add additional fields (for example, a custom "color" field for a page view). So in the original CMS directory we have Admin_Model_Page, and now I want to extend this class in the project directory with a class named Project_Model_Page (as well as new page mappers and dbtable classes).

How can I return the correct class from the shared back end implementation? That is, if Project_Class is detected and exists in that certain project's directory, return that, and if not return Admin_Class?

I'd like to avoid doing if class_exists(class) checks every time I need a different form, model, mapper, etc for every create, read, update, delete operation on every page, post, etc etc.

Is there a defined pattern to handle this? I've been looking at Factories, Service Locators, Providers and so on and so forth, but I'm not entirely certain if any of these fit this case - which is simply to have the autoloader detect if a certain class exists in one directory, and if not return a class from a default path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## The Factory-Pattern

You already were on the right track. What you might want to take a look at is the [Factory-Pattern](http://www.phptherightway.com/pages/Design-Patterns.html#factory)

By it's definition the Factory Pattern is a way to instantiate objects not by the classes constructor, but by another class or method.

That's how you probably want to roll. By it's simplest implementation the factory that you need to create here needs to take two arguments. The main class that you want to use and the fallback class in case the main class does not exist.

I will later show a few options how to improve the factory so that it will be able to automate things even further.

## Setting up everything

*For simplicitys sake I will not use an autoloader here, but using one will work just as fine.*

**Filesystem Structure**

`-Dependencies
-- DependencyRouter.php
-Fallbacks
-- FallbackRouter.php
-Interfaces
-- RouterInterface.php
-FallbackFactory.php
-index.php`

The `Dependencies` directory contains the main classes that you want to be instantiated in the first place. The `Fallbacks` directory contains the corresponding fallback class in case the main class can not be instantiated.

Since both, objects of the main class and the fallback class should be able to be used the same way we will define contracts for them. We do this by creating `Interfaces`. That's what the last folder is for.

[To not take up so much space, the gist for the actual implementations (which is not really part of the question) can be found here.](https://gist.github.com/spazecookie/bbe2144286c5b7a354bd)

Let's now have a look on the actual Factory.

```
<?php

class ClassNotFoundException extends \Exception {}

class FallbackFactory {

    public function createInstance( $main, $fallback, $instanceArgs = [] )
    {

        if( class_exists( $main) )
            $reflectionClass = new \ReflectionClass( $main );

        else if ( class_exists( $fallback ) )
            $reflectionClass = new \ReflectionClass( $fallback );

        else
            throw new ClassNotFoundException('The Class ' . $main . ' does not exist and neither does the fallback class ' . $fallback);

        return $reflectionClass->newInstanceArgs($instanceArgs);

    }

}
```

There is really nothing special going on. First we look if the actual main class does exist. If it does we will store a instance of a [`ReflectionClass`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php). If it does not we check if the fallback class exist. If it is the case we do the same as before. *You could directly instantiate an object but let's use a ReflectionClass here to keep open some neat magic we can add later.*

When neither the main class nor the exception class does exist, we should throw an Exception and pass the responsibility for handling the error to the developer.

That's really the whole magic.

**index.php**

```
<?php

require_once 'FallbackFactory.php';
require_once 'Interfaces/RouterInterface.php';
require_once 'Dependencies/DependencyRouter.php';
require_once 'Fallbacks/FallbackRouter.php';

$factory = new FallbackFactory();

$router = $factory->createInstance(
    '\Dependencies\DependencyRouter',
    '\Fallbacks\FallbackRouter'
);

$router->route();
```

That would be how to use the factory. If the main `DependencyRouter` could be found the output will be:

`I am the main Router`

If the `DependencyRouter` could not be found but the `FallbackRouter` the output will be:

`I am the Fallback router`

Otherwise an Exception will be thrown.

## Extending the Factory

If you want to make the factory act more dynamically you could do a few things.

**1. Make use of namespacing and name your classes consistent**

If you want to avoid specifying a Fallback everytime you could name your main and the fallback classes the same but specify a different namespace for them. So you would need to only pass the main class. The fallback class would be determined automatically. e.g

```
$router = $factory->createInstance(
    '\Dependencies\Router',
);
```

If `\Dependencies\Router\` is not present, the factory would automatically look for a `\Fallbacks\Router` class for example.

**2. Automatically resolve Dependencies**

At the moment we pass in the constructor arguments as a parameter to the factory method. But by making use of [Type Hinting](http://www.php.net/manual/de/language.oop5.typehinting.php) and Reflection you could automagically resolve dependencies.

**3. Specifying a Fallback-Hierarchy**

Instead of passing one fallback class you could pass an array of multiple classes that all are looked up and resolved if found.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance, really helpful. I'll then be using a factory to search for classes under one namespace, and fall back to a default namespace if not found.

Further: for each model, there is a corresponding form and mapper. Should I have one factory handle all of these 'Fallback' classes, or separate them?

EG, a default page will have its model and corresponding properties, while an extended version will add the 'color' property and form field. Should the one factory class be used to handle both, with 'model' or 'form' passed as a 'type' arg as they're both using the same namespaces?

Comment: The third parameter of the factory are the instance args which will be passed to the constructor of the class. If the main and the fallback class have different constructor signatures pass each one (for the fallback and for the main class) to the `createInstance()` method or you change the method signature to make it more like that:
https://gist.github.com/spazecookie/f97ec00837ebb1337be4

Comment: Cheers Thomas, thanks for the gist - have implemented.